# vis.js network: Edge colors not displaying in react.js app

Tags: reactjs, graph, colors, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am having a problem with the edge colors when rendering a network visualisation through a react app.

I have a MindMapComponent which contains a network.

I receive the data for the network through the props for the component:

```
class MindMapComponent extends React.Component {

//React component to display a single submission Item.
//Displays the text and author of a Perspective Item


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {map: props.mindMap, node_options: props.node_options, edge_options: props.edge_options}
}
```

I then go ahead and create the network in my `componentDidMount` function:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var edge_dataset = new vis.DataSet(JSON.parse(this.state.map.conceptmap_edges));
    var nodes_dataset = new vis.DataSet(JSON.parse(this.state.map.conceptmap_nodes));
    var data = {
        nodes:nodes_dataset ,
        edges: edge_dataset
    };
    var edge_options =JSON.parse(this.state.edge_options);
    edge_options.color = {inherit:false};
    var options = {
        edges: edge_options,
        nodes: JSON.parse(this.state.node_options),
        physics: false,
        locale: 'en',
        interaction: {
            navigationButtons: true,
            keyboard: true,
            hover: true
        }
    };
    var network = new vis.Network(this.refs.network, data,options)
    console.log(network);
}
```

And finally render the whole thing in my render function

```
render() {
    const liStyle = {
        borderStyle: 'outset',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        marginBottom: '10px',
        listStyleType: 'none'
    };

    const metaStyle = {
        paddingLeft: '15px'
    }

    const networkStyle = {
        height:'250px',
        borderRight:'dashed 2px'
    }
    var dateString = new Date(this.state.map.date_added);
    dateString = dateString.getDate() + "/" + (dateString.getMonth() +1) + "/" + dateString.getFullYear();

    return <li key={this.state.map.id} style={liStyle}>
        <div className = 'row'>
            <div className = 'col-lg-8' ref = "network" style = {networkStyle}></div>
            <div className = 'col-lg-4' style = {metaStyle}><br/><p>Submitted on: {dateString}</p></div>

        </div>
    </li>
}
```

The final network [should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQToc.png) (rendered in normal html+js app).

However in my react app the colors of the edges [do not display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5sKw.png)

I took a look inside of the network data structure (through the `console.log(network)` at the end of component did mount). 
The `body.data.edges` part of the structure contains  [the correct color value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a02E.png). However the `body.edge.[id].options.color` part is [empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm2iJ.png)

I believe this is the source of my problem but am not sure whether my analysis is correct or how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution (I ran into the same problem as you, but then in Angular2).

Try setting the color as an Object (see http://visjs.org/docs/network/edges.html) and specify the inherit property to false. E.g.(using typescript)

```
   const myEdge: Edge =  {
        id: 'myEdge',
        from: 'NODE1',
        to: 'NODE2',
        arrows: 'to',
        color: {color: '#ff0000', inherit: false};
        dashes: true
      }
```

You might also want to set the highlight and hover colors